# Delete column in data.table based on condition (row wise)

Tags: r, data.table

How can I remove every column that meets a specific condition from a specific row?
In my case remove each column with `=="-"` in the first row.

I want to do it completely inside `[ ]` without copying the data in memory, and if possible avoiding an external function.

```r
mtcars[1,c(2,4,6)] <- "-"
dt <- data.table(mtcars)
```

didn't work:

```r
temp[,.SDcols := function(x) x[1]!="-"]
temp[,.SD:= .SDcols = (function(x) x[1]!="-")]
```

works but copies the data:

```r
temp[ , .SD, .SDcols = function(x) x[1]!="-"]
```

there are other posts about this topic but my question is different because none of these posts show how to subset before looking for a condition inside the `[ ]`

[delete column in data.table in R based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879365/delete-column-in-data-table-in-r-based-on-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Removing multiple columns from R data.table with parameter for columns to remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590341/removing-multiple-columns-from-r-data-table-with-parameter-for-columns-to-remove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
 dt[,dt[1]!="-", with=FALSE]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could drop the columns containing `"-"` in the first rows by reference as follows:

```
dt[, which(c(dt[1]=="-")) := NULL]
```